# Why does my ggplot pie chart not show a legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I might have misunderstood this, but from what I read usually a pie chart on ggplot shows a legend by default. However there is none in my plot and I can't find how to put it there. I tried explicitly putting show.legend = TRUE but that didn't change anything.

I'd like to replace the geom_label() with a legend.

```
 
 library (ggplot2)

MediaPercentage2 <- data.frame(
  group = c("Messengers", "Social Media", "Other Media"),
  mediaTime = c(90, 35, 25)
)


print(
  ggplot(
    MediaPercentage2, aes(x = "", y = mediaTime), fill = group) + 
  geom_bar(stat= "identity", color = "black", fill = c("blue", "white", "orange"), show.legend= TRUE) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  geom_label(aes(label = group)
             ,position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  ggtitle ("Title"))
```

What causes the missing legend and how can I make it visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place  `fill =  group` in the `aes` argument and use `scale_fill_manual` to control the mapping between fill colour and the grouping value.

```r
library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(MediaPercentage2, aes(x = "", y = mediaTime, fill = group)) +
    geom_col(color = "black") +
    coord_polar(theta = "y")+
    geom_label(aes(label = group),
               position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
               show.legend = FALSE)+
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Messengers", "Social Media", "Other Media"), 
                      values = c("blue", "orange", "white"))+
    
    ggtitle ("Title")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
MediaPercentage2 <- data.frame(
  group = c("Messengers", "Social Media", "Other Media"),
  mediaTime = c(90, 35, 25)
)
```